# error in run a recyclerview in android project

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash

hello in my project i have a recyclerview that it's code is below

*MainActivity.java*

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyListData[] myListData = new MyListData[] {
                new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email),
                new MyListData("Info", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info),
                new MyListData("Delete", android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
                new MyListData("Dialer", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer),
                new MyListData("Alert", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert),
                new MyListData("Map", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map),
                new MyListData("Email", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email),
                new MyListData("Info", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info),
                new MyListData("Delete", android.R.drawable.ic_delete),
                new MyListData("Dialer", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer),
                new MyListData("Alert", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert),
                new MyListData("Map", android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map),
        };

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(myListData);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

*MyListAdapter.java*

```
package ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview;

/*public class MyListAdapter {
}
*/


//import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private MyListData[] listdata;

    // RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public MyListAdapter(MyListData[] listdata) {
        this.listdata = listdata;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyListData myListData = listdata[position];
        holder.textView.setText(listdata[position].getDescription());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(listdata[position].getImgId());
        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"click on item: "+myListData.getDescription(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listdata.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

*MyListData.java*

```
/*public class MyListData {
}
*/

public class MyListData{
    private String description;
    private int imgId;
    public MyListData(String description, int imgId) {
        this.description = description;
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getImgId() {
        return imgId;
    }
    public void setImgId(int imgId) {
        this.imgId = imgId;
    }
}
```

*MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java*

```
package ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview;

/*public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter {
}
*/

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvAnimalName);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        tools:context="example.javatpoint.com.recyclerviewlist.MainActivity">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*list_item.xml*

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightLarge"
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:contentDescription="Icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

*recyclerview_row.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*border.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#CCCCCC" />
</shape>
```

*build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

but when it run on android device (my android version is 4.0.4) It crashes.

and errors are:

```
06-20 13:22:46.884 19255-19255/ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview/ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4597)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at ir.mostafaheydarsana.recyclerview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4597) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:995) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how I can fix it?

Comment: What is the error or exception you got when the app crashes?

Comment: Please add crash log to the question so we can assist you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `android x` but in the main activity XML you are using `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`

change your main activity...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```